# Can you get the "code as data" of a loaded function in Clojure?

Tags: reflection, clojure

To put it another, way, "[Okay, so code is data...](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/554cdc59d8a46f01)"

That thread addresses how to read from a source file, but I'm wondering how to get the s-expression of an already-loaded function into a data structure that I can read and manipulate.

In other words, if I say,

```
(defn example [a b] (+ a b))
```

can't I get that list at runtime?  Isn't this the whole point of "code as data"?

This is really a general Lisp question, but I'm looking for an answer in Clojure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `clojure.repl/source` macro to get the source of a symbol:

```
user> (source max)
(defn max
  "Returns the greatest of the nums."
  {:added "1.0"
   :inline-arities >1?
   :inline (nary-inline 'max)}
  ([x] x)
  ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (max x y)))
  ([x y & more]
   (reduce1 max (max x y) more)))
nil
```

But this is only part of the answer. AFAICT `source` looks up the source filename and line number that define the given symbol, and then prints the source code from the file. Therefore, `source` will not work on symbols that you do not have the source for, i.e. AOT-compiled clojure code.

Coming back to your original question, you can think of `source` as reading the meta data associated with the given symbol and simply printing that. I.e. it's cheating. It's not in any way returning "code as data" to you, where with code I mean a compiled clojure function.

In my mind "code as data" refers to the feature of lisps where source code is effectively a lisp data structure, and therefore it can be read by the lisp reader. That is, I can create a data structure that is valid lisp code, and `eval` that.

For example:

```
user=> (eval '(+ 1 1))
2
```

Here `'(+ 1 1)` is a literal list which gets read by the clojure reader and then evaluated as clojure code.

**Update:** Yehonathan Sharvit was asking in one of the comments if it's possible to modify the code for a function. The following snippet reads in the source for a function, modifies the resulting data structure, and finally evaluates the data structure resulting in a new function, `my-nth`, being defined:

```
(eval
 (let [src (read-string (str (source-fn 'clojure.core/nth) "\n"))]
   `(~(first src) my-nth ~@(nnext src))))
```

The `syntax-quote` line replaces `nth` with `my-nth` in the `defn` form.

Comment: This snippet got me started down the road I'm interested in, but I believe the real answer is, No, Clojure does not internally retain the "data" representation of your functions.  This method won't work, for example, on dynamically-created functions, and as you indicated, isn't even available on pre-compiled functions after the source is gone.  To get what I'm after, it appears you'd need to use a special form-recording macro to define the functions, as suggested in [this discussion](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Lisp/comp.lang.lisp/2010-02/msg00259.html).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I do: (def x {:add-ten #(+ % 10)}), where is the code stored for (:add-ten x)? Is it stored as byte-code?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the source in recent versions of clojure with the `source` function.

```
user=> (source nth)
(defn nth
  "Returns the value at the index. get returns nil if index out of
  bounds, nth throws an exception unless not-found is supplied.  nth
  also works for strings, Java arrays, regex Matchers and Lists, and,
  in O(n) time, for sequences."
  {:inline (fn  [c i & nf] `(. clojure.lang.RT (nth ~c ~i ~@nf)))
   :inline-arities #{2 3}
   :added "1.0"}
  ([coll index] (. clojure.lang.RT (nth coll index)))
  ([coll index not-found] (. clojure.lang.RT (nth coll index not-found))))
nil
```

to get the string as a value you can wrap this in `with-out-str`:

```
user=> (with-out-str (source nth))
"(defn nth\n  \"Returns the value at the index. get returns nil if index out of\n  bounds, nth throws an exception unless not-found is supplied.  nth\n  also works for strings, Java arrays, regex Matchers and Lists, and,\n  in O(n) time, for sequences.\"\n  {:inline (fn  [c i & nf] `(. clojure.lang.RT (nth ~c ~i ~@nf)))\n   :inline-arities #{2 3}\n   :added \"1.0\"}\n  ([coll index] (. clojure.lang.RT (nth coll index)))\n  ([coll index not-found] (. clojure.lang.RT (nth coll index not-found))))\n"
user=>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful in its own right.  But this just prints the source to stdout, rather than returning the value (as I see from running `(source source)`).  Once again, maybe I just don't grok the whole idea of Lisp and functional.  Why wouldn't there be a function to *return* this information, and return it in a structured form?

Comment: editing to fix. you dont need a seperate function that returns it because you can compose this with `with-out-str`

Comment: Is there a way to modify the source of a function?

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit: You can use `source-fn` to produce the string representation of a function, and then, with some Java streaming glue, `read` it back into a Clojure list. After that you're free to manipulate the Clojure list to your hearts desire and finally `eval` it.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt: you can call `(source-fn 'nth)` instead of `(with-out-str (source nth))` to get same effect.

Comment: +1, thanks for the ideas.  The `source` function isn't quite what I was after, but is very useful to me getting started.

Answer (score 0):

That was my message; nice to meet you ;-) BTW, the references given in that thread for answers were excellent reading; so if you're interested, you might want to take the time to read them. Back to your question though `source` seems to work for code that was loaded through a file, but it doesn't work in all cases. I think, specifically, it doesn't work for functions defined in the repl.

```
user=> (def foo (fn [] (+ 2 2)))
#'user/foo
user=> (source foo)
Source not found
nil
user=> (defn foo2 [] (+ 2 2))
#'user/foo2
user=> (source foo2)
Source not found
nil
```

Digging a little bit...

```
user=> (source source)
(defmacro source
  "Prints the source code for the given symbol, if it can find it.
  This requires that the symbol resolve to a Var defined in a
  namespace for which the .clj is in the classpath.

  Example: (source filter)"
  [n]
  `(println (or (source-fn '~n) (str "Source not found"))))
nil
user=> (source clojure.repl/source-fn)
(defn source-fn
  "Returns a string of the source code for the given symbol, if it can
  find it.  This requires that the symbol resolve to a Var defined in
  a namespace for which the .clj is in the classpath.  Returns nil if
  it can't find the source.  For most REPL usage, 'source' is more
  convenient.

  Example: (source-fn 'filter)"
  [x]
  (when-let [v (resolve x)]
    (when-let [filepath (:file (meta v))]
      (when-let [strm (.getResourceAsStream (RT/baseLoader) filepath)]
        (with-open [rdr (LineNumberReader. (InputStreamReader. strm))]
          (dotimes [_ (dec (:line (meta v)))] (.readLine rdr))
          (let [text (StringBuilder.)
                pbr (proxy [PushbackReader] [rdr]
                      (read [] (let [i (proxy-super read)]
                                 (.append text (char i))
                                 i)))]
            (read (PushbackReader. pbr))
            (str text)))))))
nil
```

So yeah, it looks like it tries to load the source file off the classpath to try to spit it out for you. One thing I've learned when working with Clojure is that 9 times out of 10 it is useful to look at the source.