# how to return a clojure function as a string

Tags: string, clojure, compojure, hiccup, noir

is there any way to return a clojure function as a string? I am making some online documentation and I would really like to be able to add code into the html by somehow evaluating a function into text.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you get the "code as data" of a loaded function in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217911/can-you-get-the-code-as-data-of-a-loaded-function-in-clojure)

Comment: I think this question has a more googleable title than it's duplicate.

Comment: You might want to consider [marginalia](https://github.com/fogus/marginalia) at least for inspiration, see the [example marginalia site](http://fogus.me/fun/marginalia/) for an example of what the output looks like.

Comment: the problem I had in googling for the answer was that everything I found was about literally returning strings not the code of a function as a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [`source-fn`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html#clojure.repl/source-fn) function from the [`clojure.repl`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html) namespace:

> Usage: (source-fn x)
>
> Returns a string of the source code for the given symbol, if it can
>   find it.  This requires that the symbol resolve to a Var defined in a
>   namespace for which the .clj is in the classpath.  Returns nil if it
>   can't find the source.  For most REPL usage, 'source' is more
>   convenient.
>
> Example: (source-fn 'filter)

Comment: Thanks a lot. (source) was exactly what I needed! Seems obvious now of course ;)

Comment: just kidding, source uses print where as source-fn returns the string I needed. thanks again

Comment: Links don't work anymore.